# Raphael JS animating separate elements simultaneously

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael, graphael

I am somewhat of a rookie with svg, but do understand enough to get myself into trouble. I am looking more for a high level solution to my problem rather than exact code. Basically I have the following design which needs to be an animated path:

[image]

I am a little unsure about how I should go about creating the path, orange and white circles along the path, orange connecting paths below each points, and then animating all simultaneously when the path is updated. I am using the Raphael JS library. I already know how to create paths, circles etc etc, but really feel I am lacking a high level understanding on how to connect them together via 1 animation.

Thanks!!

Comment: this would help you. http://api.greensock.com/js/com/greensock/plugins/RaphaelPlugin.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you'd to to animate them is [`animate`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) the elements' attributes to the new values

To animate paths, you'll have to work a bit harder and write a transformPath as [seen in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11193878/484127)

#### Update:

To animate them together in sync, raphael.js offers a [animateWith](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animateWith) method that accepts these arguments:

> **Parameters**:
>
> *element* - [object] element to sync with
>
> *anim* - [object] animation to sync with
>
> *animation* - [object] animation object, see Raphael.animation

Originally seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16043974/484127) which also includes a fiddle

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was more hoping for a solution for how to animate the two TOGETHER. animating them separately is not a problem. My issue is that when animating the path, the circles along the path become "detached" even though I am animating them to the same values as the path get to. They are just separate entities and the animations do not run perfect together. Wanted to know if there was a way to do them more smoothly together. thanks